# How to mixin a module from Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I want to put my gem monkey patches into e.g. /lib/gem_ext/i18n.rb:

```
module GemExt
  module I18n
    def self.translate(*args)
      raise 'ok'
    end
  end
end
```

... and mixin into the gem through a Rails initializer gem_ext.rb.

I tried:

```
a) I18n.send :include, GemExt::I18n

b) I18n.send :include, GemExt::I18nExt

c) I18n.module_eval { include ::GemExt::I18n }

d) I18n.module_eval { include ::GemExt::I18nExt }
```

But after restarting the Rails console it doesn't raise this exception on I18n.translate("key") but shows the original behaviour and newly declared methods raise an NoMethodError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**config/initializers/gem_ext.rb**

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/gem_ext/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

**lib/gem_ext/i18n.rb**

```
module GemExt::I18n
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class << self
      def translate(*args)
        raise 'ok'
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.send(:include, ::GemExt::I18n)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monkeypatch `I18n.translate` method just write in  /lib/gem_ext/i18n.rb no need of
GemExt module.

```
module I18n
 def self.translate(*args)
   raise 'ok'
 end
end
```

Comment: It only worked for me when I call send(:include, MyModule) in the lib file and require this lib files in a initializer like this: Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/gem_ext/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}